# leetcode problem 1255 Maximum Score Words Formed by Letters

Tags: c++, string

Given a list of words, a list of single letters (might be repeating), and score of every character.

Return the maximum score of any valid set of words formed by using the given letters (words[i] cannot be used two or more times).

It is not necessary to use all characters in letters and each letter can only be used once. Score of letters 'a', 'b', 'c', ... ,'z' is given by score[0], score[1], ... , score[25] respectively

My approach is
finding score of a word
then can that word be formed or not
and finally, get the result code is given below

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    
    // score finder func
    int scoreFinder(vector<int>& score , string s){
        
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
            char ch = s[i];
            ans += score[ch -'a'];
        }
        return ans;
    }
    
    // word can be formed or not
    bool canFormed(string s , unordered_map<char,int>& myMap){
        
        for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
            if(myMap.count(s[i]) <= 0){
                return false;
                break;
            }else{
                myMap[s[i]]--;                                                                                     
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    
    int maxScoreWords(vector<string>& words, vector<char>& letters, vector<int>& score){
        
        // freq Count of letters 
       /* unordered_map<char,int> map;
        for(int i = 0; i < letters.size(); i++){
            map[letters[i]]++;
        }*/
        
        int result = 0; // final score is stored in it
        
        int idx = 0;
        while(idx < words.size()){
            
            // creating new map every time so that check for all possible words combinations
            unordered_map<char,int> myMap;
            for(int j = 0; j < letters.size(); j++){
                myMap[letters[j]] ++; //= map[letters[j]];
            }
            
            int tempResult = 0;
            for(int i = idx; i < words.size(); i++){
                string temp = words[i];
                    if(canFormed(temp , myMap)){
                        tempResult += scoreFinder(score , temp);
                    }
                }
            result = max(result , tempResult);
            idx++;
        }
        return result;
    } 
};
```

Input:

```
words = ["dog","cat","dad","good"], 
letters = ["a","a","c","d","d","d","g","o","o"], 
score = [1,0,9,5,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Output:

```
23
```

but I am getting the wrong output and I am unable to find the error in my code, my output is 33 for this testcase.

Comment: Do you want to get better at problem solving or at coding C++? The quality of code shown at leetcode is very poor (and for us hard to understand too) and should not be used to teach yourself C++. Better use a book, or a site like www.learncpp.com to get started.  So instead of me fixing this code: Try rewriting your code using smaller functions and variables with meaningful names, then attach a debugger and step through your program to see where it starts to behave differently from your expectations and you will have found your bug

Comment: The problem is that you are reinitialising the map `MyMap` for any new word. Thererefore, to decide to add a new word or not, you don't take into account that some letters have already been used by previous words. As the number of words is not so hign, you can (must ?) examine all combinations of selected words.

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor bug in your code.

In the function `canFormed` you decrement the counter als in the case where it is 0 already. We could simply add an additional `if`-statement or rewrite the whole condition.

Please see one possible solution below:

```
    // word can be formed or not
    bool canFormed(string s, unordered_map<char, int>& myMap) {

        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            if (myMap.count(s[i]) <= 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if (myMap[s[i]] > 0) {
                    myMap[s[i]]--;
                }
                else return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with backtracking in JAVA

```
public int maxScoreWords(String[] words, char[] letters, int[] score) {
    int[] counts = new int[26];
    for (char letter : letters) {
        counts[letter - 'a']++;
    }

    return wordHelper(words, counts, score, 0);

}

static int wordHelper(String[] words, int[] counts, int[] score, int index) {

    // base case
    if (index > words.length - 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    // recursive case - exclude
    int excludedSum = wordHelper(words, counts, score, index + 1);

    // recursive case - include
    int includedSum = 0;
    boolean recursionCall = true;
    int wordScore = 0;
    
    
    for (char c : words[index].toCharArray()) {
        counts[c - 'a']--;
        if (counts[c - 'a'] < 0) {
            recursionCall = false;
        }
        wordScore += score[c - 'a'];
    }

    if (recursionCall) {
        includedSum = wordScore + wordHelper(words, counts, score, index + 1);
    }
    for (char c : words[index].toCharArray()) {
        counts[c - 'a']++;
    }
    return Math.max(excludedSum, includedSum);
}
```